# Content Security Policy with Paypal button

Tags: security, paypal, content-security-policy

I wanted to set Content Security Policy (CSP) to my with page, which has a paypal button, which has gif image serves from https://www.paypalobjects.com I included it to my img-src whitelist.

```
     <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/SG/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
```

But the image is then temporarily redirect to random domains like https://akamai.mathtag.com, https://ak1s.abmr.net

How should I set CSP such that img-src includes redirect domains as well. I do not know all the redirect domains.

Comment: Why not copy the image to your server and serve it from there?

Comment: Good point. I thought they are required for their security reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSP requires that you know the domains you are referencing content from, which is one of its weaknesses.

In order to get around that, there's a few things you could do:

1. Remove the img-src whitelist from CSP altogether. This sounds sub-optimal, but unless someone is able to directly compromise your server ( in which case they could modify the CSP header anyways ), or they are able to exploit a Cross-Site Scripting attack on your site, the img-src is not a huge concern. I would worry more about the script-src section, which, if implemented properly, would likely prevent unauthorized images from being loaded anyways.
2. Create a whitelist based proxy for CSP purposes. Basically, the browser requests the image from your server, and your server then retrieves the images on the backend, following through the redirects, caches the image, and returns it to the user.
3. As SilverlightFox said, you could also store the image directly on your servers. This could be problematic if you ever need to access other images that don't comply with such a strict CSP. Also, if the buy button image changes and you are unaware of it/haven't updated it, that could create suspicion amongst potential customers who had seen the new buy button elsewhere.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Please note, Paypal states that you should only hotlink the checkout button and not save it anywhere else:

> PayPal requires that you use the PayPal Check out button and the PayPal mark image hosted on secure PayPal servers.

[Obtaining an Express Checkout Button and PayPal Mark](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReference/#obtaining-an-express-checkout-button-and-paypal-mark)

It is unclear how enforced this is.